# Alamofire : no suitable image found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alamofire

I was developing an app , in the app i am using Alamofire lib to consume webservices , everything works well in the simulator. Then i created a wildcard provision profile and tried to run in a real device, but the app crashes after splash screen and the following error log is shown. I am new to ios development , i am not aware of the solution.Searched google ,could not find the solution for this problem.  Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Enrico
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire:
>   mmap() errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/091E385A-094E-49BB-BB28-D1F37592B53D/Enrico.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
>   (lldb)

Comment: Maybe this help you https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4294